# Is there a reliable way to find out which stocks or bonds an ETF is buying?

Tags: stocks, etf, stock-markets

In general, googling for "stocks behind an ETF X" does not seem to turn up useful results about what stocks it actually represents.

I may be using the wrong search terms. For example, trying to search for stocks behind `NASDAQ: QTEC` led me nowhere.

Is there a reliable way to find out what stocks an ETF buys?

Comment: I just googled "QTEC", and the first hit took me to First Trust's summary page with a link at the top to Holdings.

Answer (score 1):

"Holdings" or "Portfolio" are the terms you are looking for. For any ETF you are interested in, all you need to do is find the ETF's summary page and find the relevant tab.

For example, search for "VOO ETF", go to the VOO page on [Vanguard.com](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/overview/voo), and click the "Portfolio" tab. Sometimes you can go straight there by entering "VOO holdings" into Google.

For QTEC specifically, it can be [found here](https://www.ftportfolios.com/Retail/Etf/EtfHoldings.aspx?Ticker=QTEC).

Answer (score 1):

The [SEC requires a prospectus for all ETFs](https://www.sec.gov/reportspubs/investor-publications/investorpubsinwsmfhtm.html#Sources), but it does not require that specific holdings be listed because they can change frequently. You will find detailed information including (1) investment objectives/goals; (2) fee table; (3) investments, risks, and performance; (4) management—investment advisers and portfolio managers; (5) purchase and sale of fund shares; (6) tax information; and (7) financial intermediary compensation.

Because ETF managers would like to encourage investment in their fund, they are generally transparent with current and prospective investors and will list their holdings in the prospectus or on the fund web site. Morningstar provides excellent summaries of most widely traded funds [like QTEC](https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/qtec/portfolio).